# return a downloadable zip file using $.post or $.get

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm making a zip file and i want to return a downloadable file but I cant figure out the return file part even tho i tried some examples i found online.

this is the code i use for this now, it does work without the `$.post()` but i need it to work with jquery. all ideas are welcome

```
$('.zipFiles').live('click', function () {
            $.post('/Home/ZipFiles');
});


//return a file
public FileResult ZipFiles()
    {
        var filesToZip = Session["DownloadQue"] as List<string>;
        var savedZipFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/") + DateTime.Now.Minute + ".zip";

        if (filesToZip != null && filesToZip.Count > 0)
            using (var zip = new ZipFile(savedZipFile))
            {                    
                foreach (string item in filesToZip)
                {
                    var path = Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/Pics/", item));
                    zip.AddFile(path, @"\cf");
                }

                zip.Comment = "this was made online";                    
                zip.Save();
            }

        return File(savedZipFile, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip);
    }
```

Comment: It is not possible to download a file using ajax

Comment: You got 25 questions with out accepted answers. Don't you like people heliping you since you show them no respect in return?

Comment: @Rune FS, you ever thought of i did not get an answer that was the right one? i rather not accept an answer then to just to accept a half as one and then somebody else with the same problem gone struggle because of that half as solution. so sure i got respect to other users. i hope that is enogh of an answer to you

Comment: All of those that I look at before I wrote the comment did actually have an answer with a solution, or where you could have enhanced the question to make it answerable or where you asked for something that's impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may return the content of file or result from an action via jQuery. Here in your code `/home/zipfiles` return .zip content and I think that you don't want to show/print zip content.

```
$('.zipFiles').live('click', function () {
            $.post('/Home/ZipFiles',"",function(data){
               alert(data);
            });
});
```

To download a file try this:

```
$('.zipFiles').live('click', function () {
   window.location.href="/home/zipfiles";              
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you can't download a file via AJAX, you'll need to do a bit of a work around.

Firstly in your action method rather than returning the zip file generate a guid (or other random but unique name) and save it to your server. Your action method should return a URL to this file.

Use the success callback for $.post to actually download the file. Have the callback parse your URL then open a new window/iframe pointing to that URL.

Answer (score 0):

I know the criteria is to use $.get or $.post...

but using "$('form').submit();" was what I was looking for and worked perfectly for me.

It leaves the user on the same page and downloads the file result.